# Soldier doesn't move in Military Outpost at This War Of Mine

Tags: this-war-of-mine

I've tried several times to loot military outpost, but every time the soldier you can trade with stays in one place and never goes inside outpost. Is it a bug or just RNG problems?

I tried running around as I saw somebody do it on youtube, but still got no effect...

Comment: It's possible you need to initiate a trade first, or at least enter the building. I remember when I did it, another soldier came in and the trade soldier excused himself. Failing that, I bet a bullet would get him moving ;)

Comment: I tried to initiate a trade but with no effect... well, seems that i have to go full rambo on them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to climb the ladder in front of trader and silently/instantly kill soldier up there. Then with few shots from shotgun i killed incoming soldiers and left without a scratch.